# I can not open Anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I downloaded and installed Anaconda3. But when I run it, nothing opens. The screen remains the same. It does not appear in the task manager either.

Comment: Spyder can not open. I tried.

Comment: what is the result of typing `python -V` in your terminal?

Comment: @briancaffey Probably "python" not recognized. Try Anaconda Promt. Assuming Windows.

Comment: @briancaffey Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)... When i tried open Anaconda, it says '' Anaconda not opening: couldn't find or load Qt platform plugin "Windows in "" ''

Comment: @B.Ozen can you search for `Anaconda Prompt` in the Windows start menu?

Comment: yes, Anaconda Promt opening.

Comment: Please be sure to have installed Anaconda under these conditions: 1) Only for your user and not for all users in your computer. 2) In a directory that does not contain spaces. 3) In a directory without non-ascii characters on it (i.e. only with characters in the English alphabet).

Comment: I selected "Just Me" and also directory is 'C:\Users\Burhan\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3' .